# Run a profile that is within a maven dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies, profile

Consider a project, DbProject, which creates a database by running a specific profile within a maven command.

If I add DbProject as a dependency to another project, ApplicationProject, can I call DbProject's profile directly from a maven command on the ApplicationProject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no you can't.

The only way to access the profile from DbPorject from within ApplicationProject is if ApplicationProject's pom has DbProject's pom as its `parent` pom. ApplicationProject would then inherit all `profiles` defined within DbProject.